# Apollo Client [BatchHttpLink] - Error Must provide query string

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

When I try to do a batch call using BatchHttpLink:

```
query = `{
   user1: getUser(id:1) {
     id
     name
     password
   }
   user2: getUser(id:2) {
     id
     name
     password
   }
}`;

apolloClient.query({
   query: gql(query),
});
```

I get:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Must provide query string."
    }
  ]
}
```

Content-Type is set to application/json.
Batch client is set like it is described into the documentation:

```
const batchHttpLink = new BatchHttpLink({ uri, headers: { batch: "true " } });
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: split(
    operation => operation.getContext().important === true,
    httpLink,
    batchHttpLink 
  ),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The query should start with `query`, `mutation` or `subscription`.

```
query = gql`query GetUsers {
   user1: getUser(id:1) {
     id
     name
     password
   }
   user2: getUser(id:2) {
     id
     name
     password
   }
}`;
```

This should work.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but the same error {"errors":[{"message":"Must provide query string."}]}

Comment: use gql`<query>` instead of passing `gql(<query>)`